# Multisigner separate readonly fields for a single document docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I want to assign a text field(read only) dynamically from code, separate for each recipient in a multi recipient embedded DocuSign using rest api (PHP SDK). How to do that using template role and tabs in php? or
How can I restrict certain fields from being viewed by specific recipients?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So your last question and the "single document" means you cannot use the [DocuSign Visibility](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility) feature of DocuSign, I assume you know about that.

So, you can have readonly fields and you can have them assign to specific recipients, but other recipients will see them too.

You can also use [pre-filled fields](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-prefill-fields) that enables to have a field that is not for any recipient and [your code can fill it in](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-customize-your-envelopes-pre-fill-fields).

What I recommend is this, since you need a template anyway. Create your template using the web app, make sure it works as you expect by trying it and sending documents to yourself using it.

Once you got it all working as expected in the web app, using the API is not that hard, all you have to do is get [API logs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw) of what the web app did using the API and you can do the same.